# Take input from user and query to a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am starting a side project to learn more about interactive web designs.

My idea is to ask the user for his favorite movie and return 4 of the most frequently appeared adjectives when the movie's name was googled.

I have created an input field and submit button, but besides that, nothing else has happened, as I don't know what my next step should be and what tool I would need.

Is there anything similar that has been done before? Perhaps I can gain some insights in these examples if they exist. Thanks!

Comment: I would explain to you that I don't possess any knowledge beyond basic HTML and CSS. So please, before you leave with a downvote, do try to walk in my shoes

Comment: I suppose you have problems connecting to DB ? You need some backend solution to do it . There are many ways and programming languages to do it , i would recommend nodeJS since it is getting popular rapidly. Create server using nodeJS, create post or get in nodeJS that would use some module for connecting to your DB , and create ajax post / get in js towards your nodeJS post / get. Else is just returning data, sending data.

I would recommend you focusing on JS and DOM manipulation, functional JS programming and so on. Before you move on to anything more complex

Comment: @noitse I honestly didn't understand a word that you said, but thanks for your suggestions. Right now I am sitting at ground zero, not even knowing what to do or where to start so I don't even know what my problems are or will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps :

- Design Database with respect to movies, ratings and search words
- Connectivity front end with the database
- show grid of results

For development you can use any MVC framework or custom framework like

- CodeIgniter
- Laravel
- Cake

Or you may start with front end technologies for example :

- angular.js

Comment: Node js is not a front end technology

Comment: @noitse : thanks for correction.

Comment: Thanks for the outline, this gives me a clear picture of what I should consider

Comment: Yup, by the way you can vote UP. Secondly you can contact me anytime for guidance.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I tried to vote up but I don't have enough reputations to immediately cast the vote. Thanks for your offer, I will definitely need more help along the way.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, best way is to use an MVC structure but since you are just starting off, you may do this using javascript and localstorage, start with some simple application like creating a register and login form, storing datas in local storage and retrieving them. Once you get used to these, move on to learn any mvc structure.

Comment: Thank you, I will go try that!